# Two real numbers, $x$ and $y$, satisfy the condition $x + y = 2 $. Show $xy(x^2+y^2) \leq 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

> > Question: Two real numbers, $x$ and $y$, satisfy the condition $x + y = 2 $.
> >     Show $xy(x^2+y^2) \leq 2$

---

What I have attempted:

Consider $$x+y=2$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (x+y)^2 = 2^2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (x+y)^2 = 4 $$

Notice that $$ x^2 + y^2 = (x+y)^2 - 2xy $$

But $(x+y)^2 = 4$

$$ \Longrightarrow x^2 + y^2 = 4-2xy $$

Now we have this inequality; $$xy(x^2+y^2) \leq 2$$

$$\Leftrightarrow xy(4-2xy) \leq 2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 2xy(2-xy) \leq 2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 2(2xy-x^2y^2) \leq 2 $$

Now I am stuck, how should I continue also is there another way to approach this question?

Comment: Moving the two over and rearranging a bit, it's $-2((xy)^2-2(xy)+1)\le 0$. Ideas?

Comment: @NathanWeckwerth I'd like to give you a tick for "answering the question".. thank you for the help

Comment: Observe that both $x$ and $y$ can't be simultaneously negative (because then the sum would be $<2$). So let us assume that $x\ge 0$. If $x\ge 2$ then in this case it is obvious that $y\le 0$ (otherwise the sum would be greater than $2$). Consequently in this case we have $xy\le 0$ and hence $xy(x^2+y^2)\le 0<2$ and we are done.

Comment: If $x\in [1,2)$ then it is obvious that $x=1+\varepsilon$ where $0\le \varepsilon<1$. Consequently, in this case we have $y=1-\varepsilon$ and hence, $$xy(x^2+y^2)=2(1-\varepsilon^2)(1+\varepsilon^2)=2(1-\varepsilon^4)\le 2$$since  $0\le \varepsilon<1$ and we are done. When $x\in[0,1)$ the argument is similar to the last case.

Comment: Hint:  you got $xy(2-xy)$ which can be considered the product of two positives with constant sum, by AM-GM, it is maximum when terms are equal, viz $xy=2-xy$.

Comment: $y=2-x \Rightarrow xy(x^2+y^2)=2-2(1-x)^4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $y=2-x$, so 
$$
x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=4-2xy=4-2x(2-x).
$$
Then
$$
xy(x^2+y^2)=x(2-x)(4-2x(2-x))
=2r(2-r),
$$
where $r=x(2-x)$.

So consider the parabola $-2r^2+4r$. It's maximum occurs at $r=-4/-4=1$ ("$-b/2a$"), so 
$$
2r(2-r)\leq 2(2-1)=2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

Let $x=r\cos \theta$; $y=r\sin\theta$. It is clear that we need only consider the case when $0 \le \theta \le \frac \pi 2$.

Since $x+y=2$ then $0\le r \le 2^\frac12$
(i.e., the longest distence from $(0,0)$ to the line $x+y=2$ when $0 \le \theta \le \frac \pi 2$).

Therefore, $$xy(x^2+y^2)=\frac12r^4\sin 2\theta \le \frac12 (2^\frac12)^4=2.$$

Comment: $$x,y$$ can be negative, right?  We have $r>0$  How can we have $0\le\theta\le\dfrac\pi2$

Answer (score 1):

First proof. $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=4-2xy=2(2-xy)$

\begin{align} (xy-1)^2 &\geq 0 \\ -2x^2y^2+4xy-2&\leq 0 \\ xy\cdot2(2-xy)&\leq 2 \\ xy(x^2+y^2) &\leq 2\end{align}

Second proof. \begin{align} \text{LHS}=\frac{1}{2} (2ab)(a^2+b^2) &\overset{\mbox{AM-GM}}{\leq} \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{(2ab+a^2+b^2)^2}{4}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{(a+b)^4}{4}=2\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Consider $f(x)= x(2-x)(x^2+(2-x)^2)$. Then $f'(x)=-8 (x-1)^3$.